# Problem with binomial coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am trying to find the sum of $$\sum_{x=0}^{n-2}\left (\frac{1}{x+1}{2x \choose x} \cdot \frac{1}{n-x-1}{2n-2x-4 \choose n-x-2}\right)\;.$$ I am told the answer is $$\frac{1}{n}{2n-2 \choose n-1}$$ Could someone show me how this is derived? I applied the binomial coefficients but am not getting anything near the answer.

Attempt: $$\frac{1}{x+1}{2x \choose x} = \frac{(2x!)}{(x!)(x!)(x+1)}$$
$$\frac{1}{n-x-1}{2n-2x-4 \choose n-x-2} = \frac{(2n-2x-4)!}{(n-x-2)!(n-2-x)!(n-x-1)}$$ I then tried to sum the product but it seems too complicated to be reduced. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried recurrence on n ?

Comment: no, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sorry, wrong word. Do you know how to prove something by induction ?

Comment: I need to derive the result, so I am not allowed to use induction here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the recurrence formular for the Catalan numbers.

Let $C_x=\frac{1}{x+1}\binom{2x}{x}$ be the x-th Catalan number.

Then what we want to show is $C_n=\sum_{x=0}^{n-2}C_{x}C_{n-x-2}$, and this has been treated in, for example see [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: sorry, I know they are catalan numbers, but those links don't really help me find the sum.

Comment: @gametheorybeginner : well... this type of recurrence relation with given initial value must have a unique solution, so the proofs in wiki page showing the formula for catalan number is the proof for recurrence relation. (and you're right the SE post I have mentioned is not the relevant one)

Comment: makes sense, thanks